# disable month end Days?

Tags: javascript, html

How to disable month end Days like 30,31, 28(feb), 29 feb(leep year)? in js calender

Comment: which calendar are you talking about? There are hundreds out there.

Comment: Date picker me download it from:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

Comment: @Pekka – I suppose the Gregorian calender. ;)

Comment: @Marcel he'd probably have to talk to the UN to get whole days disabled from that :)

Comment: yes it is Gregorian calender, me disable just last working days in this application

Answer (score 0):

To check if a date should be included, create a `Date` object from the components, then check if it contains the expected day. If the date doesn't exist, for example 2010-02-31, it will become the corresponding date in the next month, i.e. 2010-03-03.

Example:

```
function checkIfDayExists(year, month, day) {
  var d = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
  return d.getDay == day;
}
```

Comment: I just looked at the demos the OP provided, but it already does that; e.g., see http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDefaultToday.html

Comment: me also disable week end days, it is also avail at the above link, but month end is not working.

Comment: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerCustomCellRender.html
here code avail for disable week end